# Redux form: fields not updated after first submit

Tags: redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I'm using redux-form with mongodb and I can't manage to make a second submission works due to the following error:

```
{"message":"No matching document found for id \"590b02068012fb3f83e5da9d\"","name":"VersionError"}
```

which is due to the fact that the version of the document is not updated in the form.

The first submission works and data is upated; I get a new object from the REST endpoint and I set it into the state. Anyway the version value submitted by the form is not updated and this causes the error. Do I need to trigger this update manually on `onSubmitSuccess` callback?

Here's my form:

```
RegionEdit = reduxForm({
   form: 'RegionEdit', // a unique identifier for this form
})(RegionEdit);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
   initialValues: makeSelectRegion(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
      dispatch,
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegionEdit);
```

This is how I submit the form:

```
submit(values) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.dispatch(saveRegion({ values, resolve, reject }));
    });
  }
```

the following saga is executed:

```
export function* saveRegion(data) {
  const payload = data.payload.values.toJS();
  const reject = data.payload.reject;
  const resolve = data.payload.resolve;
  const requestURL = `${ENDPOINT_URL}/${payload._id}`;
  try {
    const region = yield call(request, requestURL, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      method: 'PUT' });
    yield put(regionSaved(region));
    resolve(region);
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(regionSavingError(err));
    reject(err);
  }
}
```

and `regionSaved` triggers `SAVE_REGION_SUCCESS` action which causes this code to execute in the reducer:

```
 case SAVE_REGION_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('region', fromJS(action.region));
```

I attach some screenshot
 [state field version is updated from 5 to 6 after the first successful submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXK5u.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXK5u.png)

[the payload of the second call has still old/initial version number (5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOfcZ.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOfcZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the problem was in the reduxForm instantiation, I just needed to pass property `enableReinitialize` set to `true`

```
RegionEdit = reduxForm({
   enableReinitialize: true,
   form: 'RegionEdit',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(RegionEdit);
```